# Setting up local development environment for Angular App with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I have access to an Angular app in a Github repo. I'm added as a contributor. The developers are using Grunt and I want to work with one of the branches.

To build a dev. environment locally- can I do the following?

1. Create a project folder
2. Clone the github repo. to this folder
3. NPM install  //from inside the project folder -  will this read package.json and install Grunt and the other dependencies?
4. Run grunt build

Is this the standard way of setting-up local environments? I don't want to create a branch or push anything yet.. will get to that at a later point. 
Any suggestions/ advice or tips ?

Comment: you don't need to create the folder before cloning but yes, this is the general idea. If they're using bower to set up angular, also do `bower install`. Make sure to also install grunt-cli (or bower) globally.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right _if_ there is a `Gruntfile.js` in the git repo. If there is a `bower.json` you must run `bower install` as well. After that, `grunt build `is for distribution, `grunt serve` is probably what you want.